# Extracting digits from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i need to extract the consumption figure from a single cell as detailed here (wont let me add a pic)

```
Consumption of 17258 kWh @   0.150 ppu for period 01-OCT-16 to 31-OCT-16.
```

I have used the formula

```
=MID(D62,SEARCH("",D62,15)+1,SEARCH(" ",D62,SEARCH(" ",D62,1)+4)-SEARCH(" ",D62,1))
```

but that gives me the wording Kwh as well. What do i need to do to extract this properly?

Comment: Is the string always same?

Comment: Thats fantastic, works a treat. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @LeGambler, if one of these answers solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: one more quick one, to get the dates 1 oct 16 and 31 oct 16 out ?  whats the formula?

Comment: That's not so straight forward. I suggest searching for previous similar questions and posting a new question if you don't find your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific example and assuming your string is in cell `A1`, you could use this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" kwh",A1)),"Consumption of ","")*1
```

The `*1` at the end is only needed if you want to use it as a number